# How do I get an external USB hard drive recognized in Windows PE environment (WinPE running off disc)?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, winpe

I'm running WinPE on a disc. I believe it's PE 2.0. It's being run on a laptop with USB 3.0 ports, as I'm sure that may matter. I want to connect either a USB thumb drive or USB hard drive but it's not recognizing the USB hard drive. Is it supposed to automatically detect and install drivers or are a set of commands I'm supposed to run to get it to recognize the external hard drive?

I would even be open to connecting it to the network and retrieving data in that fashion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Upgrade to a newer version of WinPE then; 2.0 is ancient; 3.0 is Windows 7; so try that

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest you do what Ramhound said, but if that's not an option you can [download drivers](http://driverpacks.net/) and inject them to your WinPE image using the servicing utilities:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749350%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613857.aspx

This links are for different versions (Vista and Win8).
I don't have access to WinPe 2, but one of them should work (assuming you have [WAIK installed](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9085)).