# External USB devices are not recognized by WinPE

Tags: boot, usb, winpe

I am attempting to push a .wim image through the latest version of WinPE and although WinPE boots up, no USB devices are recognized at all, including the one that WinPE booted from. I tried changing the formatting, NTFS nor Fat32 seem to work, I updated the BIOS (Dell OptiPlex 7040), and I tried different USB devices, and no luck. What can be causing this issue? Also, when I list disk, only the hard drive is listed.

I had initially thought USB 3.0 might have been the issue, but I also tried USB 2.0 and I ran across the same problem. I have also changed the boot method between both UEFI and Legacy with the same result. Please help.

Comment: USB 2.0 or 3.0???

Comment: [Similar Question](http://superuser.com/questions/844610/how-do-i-get-an-external-usb-hard-drive-recognized-in-windows-pe-environment-wi)

Comment: `WinPE 3.0` and `WinPE 3.1` do not support USB 3.0 devices unless the require driver is supplied to it.

Comment: Even if I put the USB devices in the USB 2.0 ports it will not work. I have used the same 3.0 setup with several new HP desktops and laptops and it works successfully.

Comment: USB 3.0 is what I have used. Without problems.

Comment: Additionally, I tried a USB 2.0 device and the problem persisted.

Comment: Update: I have downloaded the latest version of WinPE and the problem is still there. It is really odd but no USB devices are picked up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install windows anyway then simply create small partition and copy .wim file into that. After you have done it simply revert back. Also I want to know how are you making WINPE image exactly ? When you are making Winpe, is your pendrive connected ?